# How to modify appearance of Angular2 accordion? (for instance, change font size)

Tags: angular, accordion

I'd like to change the default font size of an Angular 2 accordion-group.  I've tried various styles and css, though I'm probably missing something basic.

A simplified sample of what I'm doing is:

```
<accordion [closeOthers]="oneAtATime">
  <accordion-group heading="File(s) to Upload">
  </accordion-group>

  <accordion-group heading="Images">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">New</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">Search</button>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

The accordion-group comes from angular2 bootstrap, and under the hood is using an h4 element, which is giving me a 16pt font.  I'd like to make it smaller but haven't found a way to do so.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to read the documentation fully.  You can set your accordion header like above in which case you get the default behavior.

You can also do what the documentation says and use the optional accordion-heading like this:

```
<accordion-group [isOpen]="isGroupOpened('ADMIN')">
    <div accordion-heading class="dp-accordion-header">Header</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dp-menu-btn">Item 1<button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dp-menu-btn">Item 2<button>
</accordion-group>
```